# list of all PHP preg_replace characters to escape

Tags: php, preg-replace

Where can find a **list of all characters** that must be escaped when using preg_replace. I listed what I think are three of them in the array $ESCAPE_CHARS. What other ones am I missing.

I need this because I am going to be doing a preg replace on a form submission.

So ie.

```
$ESCAPE_CHARS = array("#", "^", "[");

    foreach ($ESCAPE_CHARS as $char) {
    $_POST{"string"} = str_replace("$char", "\\$char", $_POST{"string"});
    }
    $string = $_POST{"string"};

$test = "string of text";

$test = preg_replace("$string", "<b>$string</b>", $test);
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's why we have [**`preg_quote()`**](http://php.net/preg-quote)

Comment: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: `$_POST{'string'}`? What's wrong with `$_POST['string']`?

Comment: What's wrong with `$_POST{'string'}`? (just bragging... I didn't know this syntax was valid either)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**preg_quote()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
$keywords = '$40 for a g3/400';
$keywords = preg_quote($keywords, '/');
print $keywords; 
// \$40 for a g3\/400
```