# Preg replace string with nothing; not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to edit breadcrumbs on my site by removing the delimiter on categories when I don't want to show the current page or post title. All that the code is doing is removing the spaces after the delimiter but not the delimiter [character] itself. The code is below; how do I solve this?

```
    $showOnHome = 0; // 1 - show breadcrumbs on the homepage, 0 - don't show
    $delimiter = '<span class="delimiter">|</span>'; // delimiter between crumbs
    $home = 'Home'; // text for the 'Home' link
    $showCurrent = 0; // 1 - show current post/page title in breadcrumbs, 0 - don't show
    $before = '<span class="current">'; // tag before the current crumb
    $after = '</span>'; // tag after the current crumb

    global $post;
    $homeLink = get_bloginfo( 'url' );
    
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
        
        if ( $showOnHome == 1 ) echo '<div id="crumbs" class="breadcrumbs"><a href="' . $homeLink . '">' . $home . '</a></div>';
        
    } else {
        
        echo '<div id="crumbs" class="breadcrumbs"> ';
...
elseif ( is_single() && !is_attachment() ) {
            if ( get_post_type() != 'post' ) {
                $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
                echo '<a href="' . $homeLink . '/' . $slug['slug'] . '/">' . $post_type->labels->singular_name . '</a>';
                if ($showCurrent == 1) echo ' ' . $delimiter . ' ' . $before . get_the_title() . $after;
            } else {
                $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];
                $cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
                if ($showCurrent == 0) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)\$delimiter\$#", "$1", $cats);
                echo $cats;
                if ($showCurrent == 1) echo $before . get_the_title() . $after;
            }
```

The issue is with this line of code which, I assume, should remove the delimiter but isn't doing so.

```
if ($showCurrent == 0) $cats = preg_replace("#^(.+)\$delimiter\$#", "$1", $cats);
```

I should add that it worked when I removed $delimiter from the line below, but that affected how categories nested under others showed -- say, "Movers and Shakers | Executives" --  with the separator removed yet I need it there.

```
$cats = get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
```

Comment: It may be worth having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25847711/1213708 to see if it helps.

Comment: Since you have a variable for the `$delimiter`, why not use `str_replace` instead? You don't need preg_replace for this. Or just use the `get_category_parents` without the delimiter in your `if`.

Comment: @NigelRen it isn't working, or maybe I am using it wrong.

Comment: @disinfor That (2) works but it also strips away the separator from breadcrumbs with more than one category which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Swapped out the code I was using [for this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Dimox/5654092/raw/b8730d9e4cc02d183519c51a1e945663ab9f4c64/dimox_breadcrumbs.php) and no more issues.